# How to create a addnametoselect function for custom tables

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.2.2

I need to create an `addnametoselect` function (like in customer collection) for filtering purpose in the custom collection filter by the fields in custom Table on DB in magento2. Please, anyone, help me.

Comment: please anyone help me.. this will be more helpful to me...  I'm a opencart dev and too beginner in Magento2

Comment: @Amit Bera ji please help me..

Comment: Please provide file name on which you want to implement `addnametoselect ` function?

Comment: agentcollection sir.. @AmitBera

Comment: I am asking about fields name on your want to build `addnametoselect `  on the agent module.In Magento customer collection `addnametoselect ` build on firstname, last name, middle name, prefix, SO, for your  collection which fields will be used.

Comment: for my case email contactno firstname sir.

Comment: @AmitBera  sir. i also need the prefix..

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. On which data field's you want to build this extension

Comment: @AmitBera i had a custome table named POS_Agent on that table the fields are email , contactno firstname. I need to make a colletion array like below,  $agentCollection = $this->_agents->create()->addNameToSelect();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83558/discussion-between-ask-bytes-and-amit-bera).

Answer (score 1):

try this below:

```
  public function addnametoselect($collection, $valueToFilter, $condition = 'eq')
        {
            if ($condition == 'eq') {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('name', $valueToFilter);
            } else {
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => "%$valueToFilter%"]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: MY ACTUAL NEED:
 I need to get fields by like below
public function addNameToSelect()
       {
        $fields = [];
        $agentAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('agent_account');
        foreach ($customerAccount as $code => $field) {
            if (isset($field['email'])) {$fields[$code] = $code;
            }
        } 
        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);
        return $this;
        }
On this, how to get the  getFieldset  i don't have  agent_account in my custom module what is that mean.?